# Import of SQL Script in phpmyadmin does not work

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So, I try to redo the Social Media Counter from here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/build-social-media-follower-counter/

I had some hickups on the way, but I did it so far. Now I am stuck. In the tutorial it is said to import socialCounter.sql into your database. I tried everything. Even stupidly Copy/Paste everything. It gives out a load of errors. It seems for me, who has no coding skills whatsoever, that the code inside the sql file is not in SQL or something? Here are the errors:

`enter code here97 Fehler wurden während der Analyse gefunden.`

`Unerwartetes Zeichen. (near "?" at position 2142)`

```
Unerwartetes Zeichen. (near "?" at position 2653)

Unerwartetes Zeichen. (near "?" at position 9524)

Unerwartetes Zeichen. (near "{" at position 9708)

Unerwartetes Zeichen. (near "{" at position 9785)
```

and a ton more of those. At the end:

`MySQL meldet: Dokumentation`

`#1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei '<!DOCTYPE html>`
`<html lang="en">`
`<head>`
`<meta charset="utf-8">`
`<link rel' in Zeile 1`

I have no idea what to do now. Please help, if you can. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've reached the right conclusion. It certainly seems like you're not importing the .sql file, because the error message specifically references the file starting with `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <link rel` (which is probably an HTML file). Looking at the socialCounter.sql file in the paulfp repository, it definitely is proper SQL syntax, so the only conclusion I can draw is that you're not importing the correct file.

Is the file correct on your disk? If you use a text editor to look at socialCounter.sql, does it start with a line line `<!DOCTYPE html>` or with `-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump` as the SQL file does?